# How to retrieve data from ServiceNow using Camel framework?

Tags: java, apache-camel, servicenow

I am trying to get data from ServiceNow table using Apache Camel. Here is my code:

```java
CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();

    ServiceNowComponent snc = new ServiceNowComponent();
    snc.setInstanceName("test-servicenow");
    snc.setApiUrl("dev91510.service-now.com");
    ServiceNowConfiguration snc_config = new ServiceNowConfiguration();
    snc_config.setApiVersion("LONDON");
    snc_config.setPassword("123");
    snc_config.setUserName("admin");
    snc_config.setTable("task_time_worked");
    snc_config.setApiUrl("dev91510.service-now.com");
    snc.setConfiguration(snc_config);
    try {

        context.addComponent("test-servicenow", snc);
        context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                from("servicenow:test-servicenow?userName=admin&password=123&apiUrl=https://dev91510.service-now.com/api/now/table/task_time_worked").to("log:data");
                }
        });

        context.start();

        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } finally {
        context.stop();
    }
```

I get an error:

> Consumer not supported

I am new at working with Camel. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Camel docs for the [servicenow-component](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/servicenow-component.html) have an example of data retrieving, so according to it, you should use `to` instead of `from` along with the `CamelServiceNowAction = RETRIEVE` header